# Difference between Xcode Project testing and Pre-release internal testing

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, xcode-project

I'm done with testing my app on all my devices through building the app on Xcode Project. Do I now need a distribution certificate or can I use my development certificate to use iTunes Connect pre-release internal testing thing?

I'm the only one who worked on my app so what would be the difference between testing my app on iTunes Connect pre-release internal tester and the way i've been doing it by building app onto device with Xcode project from desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that you do need a distribution certificate and provisioning file since you are uploading a build into iTunesConnect which could then be used for app submission.

In addition to the distribution provisioning, one other difference between an Xcode install and uploading to iTunesConnect is that your binary will go thru the verification process - that process may find issues with missing icon sizes, etc.